# Is there an accepted way of discouraging serial tagging?

Tags: discussion, tags, behavior

Recently I have seen a few users that edit almost every question related to certain topics, adding what appears to be a "canned" series of tags, regardless of whether they apply to the question or not.  For instance, editing all the `ios` questions and adding `iphone`, `objective-c`, `ipad`, etc.

Is there an accepted way of discouraging this behavior?

Comment: For which questions were the tags changed, old questions or new questions?

Comment: Both, but mostly new. But its

Comment: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6654384/2) edit, for instance, the `ios` tag was removed and `iphone` and `objective-c` added, though the question isn't particular to iphone nor about the objective c language.

Comment: Argh! That's annoying. The number of questions that I've seen that apply only to either iPhone or iPad, instead of iOS, is minuscule, and yet some people insist on applying iPhone to questions where it's irrelevant.

Comment: I'd suggest flagging for a moderator, but I'm not totally sure what they'd even be able to do about it. +1 for a good question

Comment: Are these *suggested edits*, or do the users responsible have tag editing privileges?

Comment: @Cody On the latest example the user in question has enough rep to retag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a pattern (rather than one or two instances of bad tagging) start flagging them for moderator attention when you roll back the edit so that moderators may attempt some gentle user education.